# How do I fold patches (qfold) in TortoiseHg 2.x?

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg, mercurial-queue

I've seen a few tutorials that talk about qfold and how to do it in TortoiseHg 1.x, but I can't figure out where the button for folding patches is in 2.x. The [official documentation](http://tortoisehg.bitbucket.io/manual/2.0/patches.html) doesn't mention it at all. Does anybody know how to do it?

Comment: Same way as before, only Workbench view was changed

Answer (score 22, accepted):

There's no button, and the "Patch Queue" view doesn't do it.  Instead:

1. Have at least one patch applied.
2. Select one or more unapplied patches in the graph view.
3. Right-click and select "Fold patches...".